# How to get all possible combinations of K items from a total of N in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

For e.g., if `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` is a vector, then all possible combinations of 3 items at a time is

```
 4     5     6
 3     5     6
 3     4     6
 3     4     5
 2     5     6
 2     4     6
 2     4     5
 2     3     6
 2     3     5
 2     3     4
 1     5     6
 1     4     6
 1     4     5
 1     3     6
 1     3     5
 1     3     4
 1     2     6
 1     2     5
 1     2     4
 1     2     3
```

How do I find this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/combnk.html). Basically you just need to type `c = combnk(1:6,3)`. Hope it helps.

Edit: The difference between what I proposed and @nash 's `combntns` is the toolbox that the commands are in. `combnk` is in the Statistics Toolbox, while `combntns` is in the Mapping Toolbox.

Answer (score 3):

```
>> combos = combntns([1 2 3 4 5 6], 3)
```

Output:

```
 1     2     3
 1     2     4
 1     2     5
 1     2     6
 1     3     4
 1     3     5
 1     3     6
 1     4     5
 1     4     6
 1     5     6
 2     3     4
 2     3     5
 2     3     6
 2     4     5
 2     4     6
 2     5     6
 3     4     5
 3     4     6
 3     5     6
 4     5     6
```

Answer (score 3):

I use:

```
allCombos = nchoosek([1:n],k);
```

I prefer this, as `nchoosek` comes with Matlab, no toolbox needed.