# Matrix Basis expansion

Tags: matlab

MATLAB:

I am trying to do basis expansion of a huge matrix(1000x15). 
For example,

X =

```
x1   x2

1    4

2    5

3    6
```

I want to build a new matrix.

Y =

```
x1   x2    x1*x1   x1*x2   x2*x2

1    4       1       4       16

2    5       4       10      25

3    6       9       18      36
```

Could any one please suggest a easier way to do this

Comment: I don't get it.  What happens if you have three columns? What is the expected output?

Comment: If there are 3 columns let's say, x1, x2 and x3. Output matrix Y will have x1,x2,x3,x1*x1,x1*x2,x1*x3,x2*x2,x2*x3,x3*x3

Comment: So you want a matrix that considers all variables (single columns) and all possible combinations of pairs?

Comment: Is the ordering important?  Because building `[Y,Y.^2,Ycomb]` is easier.

Comment: Please post any code attempts you have made.

Comment: I can't right a code for you now but here is an approach. Assume that you vectorize the matrix as `[x_1;x_2;...;x_N]`. Now, use [a vectorized approach for block matrix multiplication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21357692/matlab-block-matrix-multiplying-without-loops) to perform the following multiplication: `[x_1;x_2;...;x_N] * [x_1,x_2,...,x_N]`. Then only take the upper/lower triangular matrix. That should give you the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the one-liner from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29319387/3121310) to get the 2-combinations of the indices, you can generate the matrix without the interleaved ordering with

```
function Y = columnCombo(Y)
    comb  = nchoosek(1:size(Y,2),2);
    Y     = [Y , Y.^2 , Y(:,comb(:,1)).*Y(:,comb(:,2))];
end
```

For the interleaved ordering, I came up with this, possibly sub-optimal, solution:

```
function Y = columnCombo(Y)

    [m,n] = size(Y);
    comb  = nchoosek(1:n,2);
    Y     = [Y,zeros(m,n + size(comb,1))];

    col = n+1;
    for k = 1:n-1
        Y(:,col) = Y(:,k).*Y(:,k)                       ;
        ms       = comb(comb(:,1)==k,:)                 ;
        ncol     = size(ms,1)                           ;
        Y(:,col+(1:ncol)) = Y(:,ms(:,1)).*Y(:,ms(:,2))  ;
        col = col + ncol + 1                            ;
    end
    Y(:,end) = Y(:,n).^2;

end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
% your input
A = [1 4; 2 5; 3 6];

% generate pairs
[p,q] = meshgrid(1:size(A,2), 1:size(A,2));

% only retain unique pairs
ii = tril(p) > 0;

% perform element wise multiplication
res = [A A(:,p(ii)) .* A(:,q(ii))];
```